# How to execute helper methods from inside a yml file in Middleman?

Tags: ruby, internationalization, yaml, middleman

I have a Middleman app, which uses **yml** files to store *data* and translation *locales*.

Is there a way that i can access helper methods from within these files? Appending **.erb** at the end of those files does not work as it causes Middleman to throw an exception.

Comment: What is the error message you get from using a `.yml.erb`file? Maybe there's a workaround...

Comment: @TomLord: It gives me an UnknownFileType error: `load_file': can not load translations from /path/to/locales/de.yml.erb, the file type erb is not known (I18n::UnknownFileType)`

Comment: Oh, so the `yml` file you're talking about is actually a language translation?....

Comment: In which case, why do you want to make that a dynamic `erb` file? What's your use case? Would it not be better to just use string interpolation?

Comment: @TomLord the use case it that my translation files contain some markup, like links. I would like to use middleman's helper methods to generate those links, as they respect I18n settings.

Comment: I still don't see any need to make the file dynamic. I'd rather just place any middleman helper methods into the view/helpers, and use string interpolation in the language file.

Comment: @TomLord i have the feeling i am missing something very obvious, but how would i go about doing string interpolation in the language file?

Comment: You see all of those translations that contain text like: `%{blablabla}`? That's an interpolation.

Comment: @TomLord i know what string interpolation is, but as far as i have tried, it is not possible from within yml files. I can use it in erb files using the ruby-specific `#{}` syntax, but not in yml. Or am i missing something?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you DON'T try to do that. Just make it a string interpolation (`%{foobar}`) and then in your view/helpers do stuff like: `I18n.t('your.translation.key', foobar: MiddlemanHelper(this_is_not_real_code))`

Comment: Ohh, now i get it. I did not know it was possible with middleman's localization module. Looks a lot like the rails one! Cool, thank you a lot!